# Existe t-il un adjectif pour "qui n'a pas lieu d'être ?" "Qui ne devrait pas être/exister ?"

Tags: vocabulaire

J'aimerai dire : "une culpabilité qui n'a pas lieu d'être" en voulant signifier que la personne n'est en fait pas fautive de ce pour quoi elle culpabilise. Y aurait-il un adjectif qui pourrait remplacer ce "qui n'a pas lieu d'être" ?

Merci d'avance

Answer (score 9):

Je dirais :

> Une culpabilité infondée.

Comment: Pour le cas cité, je pense que cette proposition est la meilleure. Dans un cas plus général, si l'on veut insister sur l'aspect philosophique du concept (comme on distingue ce qui devrait exister  – le nécessaire – de ce qui ne devrait pas exister – le contingent), je pense que le terme *aberrant* pourrait être employé, puisque est aberrant ce qui s'écarte de la logique, donc ce qui, du point de vue de la norme, ne devrait pas exister.

Comment: @KOthetypo Oui, c'est une possibilité. Je trouve cependant qu'il y a une gradation dans l'aberrance alors que *qui n'a pas lieu d'être* est plus binaire.